# Optimally cutting a stick at specified locations

Tags: algorithm

> You have to cut a stick with length `l` into several pieces. Cuts have to be made at locations `c1, c2, c3, ..., cn`, where `ci` is an integer between `1` and `n-1` (inclusive). The cost of a cut is equal to the length of the stick on which it is made. What should be the order of the cuts to minimize the overall cost of the operation?
>
> For example, consider a stick of length `10` and cuts have to be made at locations `2, 4, 7`. You could cut the sticks in the order given. The first cut would cost `10`, since the stick is of length `10`. The second cut would cost `8`, since the remaining stick on which the cut is made is of length `10 - 2 = 8`. The last cut would cost `6`, since the length of the remaining stick is `10 - 4 = 6`. The total cost is `10 + 8 + 6 = 24`
>
> But if we cut the stick in the order: `4, 2, 7`, we get the cost of `10 + 4 + 6 = 20` which is better for us.
>
> Design an algorithm to solve the problem.

I'm pretty sure this is a DP problem. A tantalizing recurrence relation I could see was the fact that if we cut a stick, we get two smaller sticks. If we know the optimum solution for these two sticks, we can easily figure out the optimum solution for the larger stick. But this would be very inefficient.

If you have a recursive function `min_cost(stick_length, c_1, c_2, ..., c_n)` which returns the minimum cost of cutting a stick of length `stick_length` at `c_1, c_2, ..., c_n`, the recurrence relation would look something like this

```
min_cost(stick_length, c_1, c_2, ..., c_n) =
    stick_length 
    + minimum(min_cost(c_1, a_1, a_2, ..., a_i) 
    + min_cost (stick_length - c_1, 
                a_(i+1), ..., a_(n-1)),
                min_cost(c_2, a_1, a_2, ..., a_i) 
    + min_cost(stick_length - c_2, 
               a_(i+1), ..., a_(n-1)), ... , 
               min_cost(c_n, a_1, a_2, ..., a_i)
    + min_cost(stick_length - c_n,
                a_(i+1), ..., a_(n-1)))`,
```

where `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n` is a permutation of the remaining places to be cut. We will have to pass all possible permutations to the recurrence function not just one as I have written.

This is obviously impractical. How do I solve this?

Comment: ^That is exactly what I want to know too.

Comment: I don't think the complete solution would be too complex. This question is from an informatics olympiad.

Comment: @Gerard every time made a cut, you will divide the whole stick into 2 another sticks, so you only need to call another recursive function for that two sticks, which help to reduce the formula. Just need to sort the c1, c2 ... and handle some calculations.

Comment: @PhamTrung: I don't know which cuts to make on which stick. How will sorting in ascending order help?

Comment: How do I contact Andrew Barber? I don't know why he put this on hold. And he hasn't even commented yet.

Comment: @Gerard because for example, you cut stick at ci, so there are two pieces, the first part can only be cut at c1 to ci-1, the second part is only from ci+1 to cn.So just a for loop and the method only need two params denote start and end indexes, which can be used for DP

Comment: @Gerard the above approach can only be applied if the list c1,c2... has been sorted

Comment: This does look like DP. You say that if you knew the cost of the best answer for each smaller size of a stick that might be produced from a cut you could work out the best answer for a stick but then dismiss this as too inefficient. But with DP you work out the best answer for lengths 1, 2, 3, 4... and then store the best answer and cost of those lengths. At each stage you can just look up the best cost for smaller lengths so it is not as inefficient as if you were recursing to solve the smaller problems - you only solve each sub-problem once.

Comment: An idea may be: for each cut, the possible lengths of stick at which the cut can be made = n. So you can make an nxn matrix of cost[remainingLength][Ci]. You can then build this into a DP matrix by summing the individual costs to the total cost upto now and form the recurrence relation accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One more DP solution:

Let's COST(a,b) is the best cost of cutting the segment between a-th and b-th cut point. It is clear that COST(a,a) and COST(a,a+1) is zero. We can compute the best value of COST(a,b) as minimum of cuts through all the middle points a+1...b-1 plus own segment length. So we can fill triangle table diagonal by diagonal and find final result as COST(start,end) with O(N^3) time complexity and O(N^2) space

Delphi code (outputs `Cost 20  Sequence 4 2 7`)

```
var
  Cuts: TArray<Integer>;
  Cost: array of array of Integer;
  CutSequence: array of array of String;
  N, row, col, leftpos, rightpos, cutpos, Sum: Integer;
begin
  Cuts := TArray<Integer>.Create(0, 2, 4, 7, 10); // start, cuts, end points
  N := Length(Cuts);
  SetLength(Cost, N, N);  //zero-initialized 2D array
  SetLength(CutSequence, N, N);  //zero-initialized 2D array

  for rightpos := 2 to N - 1 do
    for leftpos := rightpos - 2 downto 0 do begin //walk along the diagonals
                                                  //using previously computed results
      //find the best (mincost) cut
      Cost[leftpos, rightpos] := MaxInt; //big value
      for cutpos := leftpos + 1 to rightpos - 1 do begin
        Sum := Cost[leftpos, cutpos] + Cost[cutpos, rightpos];
        if Sum < Cost[leftpos, rightpos] then begin
          Cost[leftpos, rightpos] := Sum;
          //write down best sequence
          CutSequence[leftpos, rightpos] := Format('%d %s %s', [Cuts[CutPos],
            CutSequence[leftpos, cutpos], CutSequence[cutpos, rightpos]]);
        end;
      end;

      //add own length
      Cost[leftpos, rightpos] :=
        Cost[leftpos, rightpos] + Cuts[rightpos] - Cuts[leftpos];
    end;

  //show the best result
  Caption := Format('Cost %d  Sequence %s',[Cost[0, N-1], CutSequence[0, N-1]]);
```

Comment: That's the exact same solution I came up after some rethinking.

Comment: @MBo Why have you added 0 (first element) and 10 (last element) in Cuts?

Comment: @user248884 0 and 10 are end coordinates needed to get lengths of the first and last segments

Comment: Yes. But my question is why do we need them in the Cuts array?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your doubts, but it seems the simplest way to account for lengths in expression `Cost[leftpos, rightpos] + Cuts[rightpos] - Cuts[leftpos];`

Comment: @MBo I mean, Since the cuts array is not the DP array so certainly they are not the base cases. Cut array represents a set of points where the rod has to be cut. By adding 0 and 10, we are implying that the rod has to also be cut at these points which is redundant. Hence my difficulty in wrapping my head around this. How did you arrive that we need to add the 0 and the final total length to the Cuts array. What was the thought process?

Comment: @user248884 I wanted to get final result `COST(start,end)`, so ends were important for me.  I don't remember exact details four years later :) But note that description contains phrases like `cut is made is of length 10 - 2 = 8`

Comment: What kind of syntax is this ?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a problem from the UVa Online Judge. http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=944

In this problem L < 1000 and n < 50.

As I mentioned in the comments, if you notice then for each cut, the possible lengths of stick at which the cut can be made = n.

The total possible `remaining lengths` shall be finite and for each remaining length the number of `sets of cuts remaining` shall also be finite. So you can build a DP on the remaining lengths.

Starting from the smallest, for each 'remaining length', you can calculate the minimum cost of cutting it down further.

Something like:

```
DP[k][SetOfCutsRemaining] = k + Min( DP[m1][SetOfCutsRemaining till c1] 
                                 + DP[k-m1][SetOfCutsremaining from c1], 
                                 DP[m2][SetOfCutsRemaining till c2] 
                                 + DP[k-m2][SetOfCutsremaining from c2],... )
                           where mi are the lengths remaining if we make a cut at ci
```

You will then need to do this till `DP[L][InitialSetOfCuts]`.

In the example problem, `L = 10, ci = 2, 4, 7`

The remaining lengths and their corresponding cuts remaining are as follows. **Note that the number of combinations shall be C(n+2,2) = (n+2)(n+1)/2 = 10 in this case**

```
2 {} (2 times, 0-2 and 2-4)
3 {} (2 times, 4-7 and 7-10)
4 {c1}
5 {c2}
6 {c3}
7 {c1, c2}
8 {c2, c3}
10 {c1, c2, c3}

DP[2][{}] = 0 (No cut remaining)
DP[3][{}] = 0 (No cut remaining)
DP[4][{c1}] = 4 (1 cut remaining)
DP[5][{c2}] = 5 (1 cut remaining)
DP[6][{c3}] = 6 (1 cut remaining)
DP[7][{c1,c2}] = 7 + Min( DP[2]{} + DP[5][{c2}], DP[3]{} + DP[4][{c1}] )
               = 7 + Min( 5, 4 ) = 11.
DP[8][{c2,c3}] = 8 + Min( DP[2]{} + DP[6][{c3}], DP[3]{} + DP[5][{c2}] )
               = 8 + Min( 6, 5 ) = 13.
DP[10][{c1,c2,c3}] = 10 + Min( DP[2]{} + DP[8][{c2,c3}], DP[4]{c1} + DP[6][{c3},
                                DP[7][{c1,c2}] + DP[3]{} )
               = 10 + Min( 13, 10, 11 ) = 20.
```

Comment: Could you build a DP matrix for the example in the question to illustrate?

Comment: @Gerard Example added for illustration. Note that there can be multiple sets of cuts remaining for a single remaining length. Here in this example, there is only one set per remaining length (if I haven't left out any)

Comment: Can you point out how to represent the set of remaining cuts? That is the key point for this solution.

Comment: @PhamTrung That implementation is dependent on the programming language. In C++ I would use a vector of sets for each remaining length.

Answer (score 2):

First, assuming we have an ascending-order array of cutting position, so in OP example, it will be
{2,4,7}

At first, we have the stick with length from 0 to n, so we call function

```
int cal(int start, int end , int [] cuts)
```

with start = 0 and end = n.

For every cutting point which is greater than start and less than end, we have the formula

```
int result = 1000000;
for(int i = 0; i < cuts.length; i++){
   if(cuts[i]> start && cuts[i]<end){
         int val = (end - start) + cal(start, cuts[i], cuts) + cal(cuts[i],end , cuts); 
         result = min(val, result);
   } 
}
```

and the **DP table** can be simply

```
dp[start][end]
```

So, the whole solution will be:

```
int cal(int start, int end, int[]cuts){
    if(dp[start][end]!= -1){//Some initializations need to be done
        return dp[start][end];
    }
    int result = 1000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < cuts.length; i++){
       if(cuts[i]> start && cuts[i]<end){
         int val = (end - start + 1) + cal(start, cuts[i], cuts) + cal(cuts[i],end , cuts); 
         result = min(val, result);
       } 
    }
    return dp[start][end] = result;
}
```

To further enhance the space using, we can refer each cut position *as its index* in the array `cuts`.

Added start and end point to the cut arrays, we have following arrays

```
{0,2,4,7,10}
```

By referring to start position as index 0, end as index 4, we can decrease the space of array dp from dp[10][10] to dp[5][5]

Comment: If I am not wrong, then isn't this the exact solution that OP already tried out?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal As OP mentioned, his solution is impractical, so I just show him another approach:)

Comment: IMO this will not be efficient enough because the length 2 to 7 shall be obtained by making cuts at 2 and 7 in the order (2,7) and (7,2) respectively and hence it shall have repeated calculations.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal can you illustrate a little bit more? for a cut at 2 and 7 , the state from (0,10) will become (0,2) and (2,10) , then from start (2,10) it will become (2,7) and (7,10). And of course using DP will avoid repeated calculations

Comment: I may have misunderstood your solution. Are you using DP or recursion? From your code it seems to be recursion. If this is so, then state (2,7) shall have to be calculated for both (2,10) and (0,7).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal mine is DP, I also mention about how to build DP table in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can buzz like a fridge anytime, but talking in maths is more of a problem. I probably could formalize the algorithm for the life of me, but as long as the karma police leaves me alone, I won't.

Here is my solution (in JavaScript).

It's a pure brute-force approach.
Not a single cut (if I may say so), all branches are taken.

It appears the number of explored cuts for n cuts is equal to 3^^n (I did measure it). I suspect there is a trivial explanation for that, but trying to find it makes my head buzz, so...

I use the format suggested in another comment, i.e. the leftmost and rightmost elements of the array are representing the ends of the current bit of stick.
For instance, `[0,2,4,7,10]` means "cuts at positions 2, 4 and 7 in a stick ranging from 0 to 10".

```
function try_cut_raw (list)
{
    // terminal ends
    if (list.length == 2) return 0;
    if (list.length == 3) return list[2]-list[0];

    // left and right split
    var cost_min = 1e6;
    for (var i = 1 ; i != list.length-1 ; i++)
    {
        var cost = try_cut_raw (list.slice (0, i+1))
                 + try_cut_raw (list.slice (i, list.length));
        if (cost < cost_min) cost_min = cost;
    }
    return cost_min+list[list.length-1]-list[0];
}
```

A more refined one, returning a semi-ordered sequence of the cuts to be applied to achieve the result.

```
function try_cut (list)
{
    // terminal ends
    if (list.length == 2) return { cost: 0, seq:[] };
    if (list.length == 3) return { cost: list[2]-list[0], seq:[list[1]] };

    // left and right split, retaining best value
    var i_min;
    var cost_min = 1e6;
    var seq_min;
    for (var i = 1 ; i != list.length-1 ; i++)
    {
        var cl = try_cut (list.slice (0, i+1));
        var cr = try_cut (list.slice (i, list.length));

        var cost = cl.cost+cr.cost;
        if (cost < cost_min)
        {
            cost_min = cost;
            // store cut order associated with best result
            seq_min  = [list[i]].concat (cl.seq).concat(cr.seq);
        }
    }
    return { cost: cost_min+list[list.length-1]-list[0], seq: seq_min }
}
```

A test case with the OP's input and both examples from the initial challenge page

```
function cut (list)
{
var cut = try_cut (list);
var cut_raw = try_cut_raw (list);
console.log ("["+list+"] -> "+cut.seq+" cost "+cut.cost+"/"+cut_raw);
}

cut ([0,2,4,7,10]);
cut ([0,25,50,75,100]);
cut ([0,4,5,7,8,10]);
```

output

```
[0,2,4,7,10] -> 4,2,7 cost 20/20
[0,25,50,75,100] -> 50,25,75 cost 200/200
[0,4,5,7,8,10] -> 4,7,5,8 cost 22/22
```

Answer (score 0):

I respect to all above solution, Here is a my solution for this problem in Java.

This might be helpful for someone.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CutTheSticks2 {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        short N = Short.parseShort(br.readLine());
        short[] A = new short[N];
        N = 0;
        for (String str : br.readLine().split(" ")) {
            A[N++] = Short.parseShort(str);
        }

        Arrays.sort(A);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println(N);
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            if (A[i - 1] != A[i]) {
                sb.append((N - i) + "\n");
            }
        }

        // OUTPUT
        System.out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a solution ? Can you please explain it with input and output ?