# How is Matrix Chain Multiplication a special case of shortest path in DAG?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can DP algorithm for Matrix Chain Multiplication be modeled as shortest path in DAG? I read somewhere that every DP problem is a walk on an implicit DAG but I am unable to visualize those problems in which a transition leads to more than one state ( or sub-state ).

One more example where I fail to visulize the same is [UVA 10003](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=944). A DP solution of the above is discussed here: [Cutting a stick such that cost is minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106595/cutting-a-stick-such-that-cost-is-minimized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine that there is a directed edge between two states if we can go from the first state to the second one(of course, a state can consist of several parameters). There are no cycles in this graph, so it is DAG. So visualizing a DAG itself is not hard(you can just write down all states and edges between them). But is not necessary can modeled as a shortest path search. For example, in a problem about cutting a rope the value for a state is a sum of values for two other states, so it is not even a path. Anyway, it might impractical to visualize a solution if the number of parameters is very big. And there is no need to do any visualization to solve a problem and prove the correctness of your solution.

Comment: My question is about when you go to two states in a single transition like:

for i from a+1 to b-1:
Cost(a,b) = Cost(a,i) + Cost(i,b) + Length(a,b)

In this case there should be an edge of weight Length(a,b) which goes from (a,b) to state (a,i) & (i,b). Making two separate edges is probably wrong here because you cannot go to either of the state independently.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal The claim that we can represenet any dynamic programming solution as a shortest path in a DAG is wrong(or, at least, it requires a more clear and detailed defenition).

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I read this in "Competitive Programming" book and when I wrote to the author, I got following response:
"The more complex the DP is, the harder it is to think as a DAG. The explanation to view DP as DAG is only helpful for easier DPs, that's my current opinion."
And so I am accepting your answer.